# Script list MAX CPUs per OS Version/Edition

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, scripting

I need a vbscript that lists the MAX Supported CPUs OS Version / Edition, since Windows 2000 until now (Windows 2012 r2).

The output would be something like this:

Example Windows 2003 Standard x86: MAX CPU: 4
Example Windows 2003 Enterprise x64: MAX CPUS: 8
Example Windows 2008 Standard x64: MAX CPU: XXXX
Example Windows 2008 Enterprise x64: MAX CPUS: XXXX

and so on...

Anyone have some example of this? The OS doesn`t have any WMI class that dumps this information?

Thank you.

Comment: You won't find limitations for other OSes than your current one in Windows (I'm not even sure you will find for the current OS). The limitations are available one technet, so google and build yourself a script with an array or hashtable to store the values.  You also do not specify what you mean by CPUs.  Cores, sockets, with/without hyper threading....

Comment: I'm pretty certain this information is not available from the OS. Google shows some comparison charts, but nothing even close to ranging from Windows 2000 to Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: The Goal is to display the MAX Physical CPU (socket) supported per version/Edition.